# How to change an Activity's background color from another Activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, background

I'm working on a launcher app. In which I've made the Home `Activity`, and a Settings `Activity` for setting the launcher. In settings `Activity` I've implemented an `AmbilWarna ColorPicker` through which I want to select a color and apply it to Home `Activity`. Means I want to set Home `Activity`'s color from Setting's `Activity`. I tried to do it by `findViewById` but my app crashes. Any solution to this? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer on my own. I saved the value in the `SharedPreferences` in my Settings `Activity` and got the value from `onCreate` in my Home `Activity` it works!

**Settings:**

```
Settings.this.findViewById(R.id.settings)
                                .setBackgroundColor(color);
                        edit = colors.edit();
                        edit.putInt("color_code", color);
                        edit.commit();
```

**Home:**

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.home);

        colors_app = getSharedPreferences("MyColor2", 1);

        int colorcode2 = colors_app.getInt("color_code", 0);
        if (colorcode2 != 0) {

            Home.this.findViewById(R.id.home_layout)
                    .setBackgroundColor(colorcode2);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. You can select your answer as a correct one.